# Using local private key to push a repository to a git server (github) on a remote server

Tags: git, ssh, git-push, private-key

I have a private key that has access to my GitHub (Also I use it to connect a bunch of servers through SSH) and I use it to push/pull on my GitHub.

I have to develop code on a server with the SSH Remote option of VSCode, and it's nice to develop and run codes on the server but there is a problem.
When I finished the code, I could not push my commits to GitHub because my private key was not on that server.

I develop on different servers, I do not want to share my local private key and put it on any other server.

I do not know what should I do. should I create a private key for each server?
then give assign it to the corresponding repository on GitHub?

OR

Can I just use my local private key (that I am using to connect the remote servers & has access to my GitHub) just for push? it would be great if we had this option

Is there any option like this? "using your local ssh key on a remote shell without copying it on the remote server"?

When I search about this, I just get how to set up ssh on a remote server or how to set up an ssh key for GitHub. I tried searching keywords like "tunneling private key" or... It did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [SSH Agent Forwarding](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/using-ssh-agent-forwarding). With forwarding enabled, any identities that you have loaded into your local ssh-agent will also be usable from remote servers.